# How to calculate the correlation of yield curve extrema?

Tags: regression, data, yield-curve

The goal is to reproduce this chart:

[image]

I first looked at the legend. It reads: "Correlation of Front and Back Fed Funds curve, Pivoted Around Peak Rate (Rolling 250 Day). Then I noticed that the Y-axis is in "%" which is a unit that I have not seen used for correlations. After all, it's a unitless measure, assuming we're talking about the rather axiomatic statistical form of "correlation":

$$ Cor = \frac{Cov_{xy}}{\sigma_x\sigma_y} $$

After a bit more contemplation I thought perhaps it's actually a rolling regression, given the 250 window. But if that was the case, then the y axis would be in beta space if I'm not mistaken (again not %).

### Question

The good news is that yield curve data is in the public domain, so getting the high and low ends should be straight forward, the question is once I have daily time series for front/back of the curve for all those years, what do I do with it to get the chart as pictured above? By this I mean the calculation for the y-axis.

Comment: Correlations as defined statistically (covariance divided by product of standard deviations) must be between $-1$ and $+1$.  If you multiply these by $100\%$ then you would say they must be between $-100\%$ and $+100\%$.

Comment: @Henry Ah, you're totally right. Now it makes some sense.